Form Data Not Inserting Into Database Despite Validation Success
I'm working on a product inventory management system using CodeIgniter. I have created a form that collects product information such as brand name, generic name, category, and pricing details. My problem is that while the form validation is successful, the data doesn't seem to be getting inserted into the database.
Controller InventoryController.php
Here is my addProduct() function that handles the form submission, validation, and passing of data to the model:
    public function addProduct() {
            $this->load->model('Inventory_model');
            $data = $this->input->post();

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand_name', 'Brand Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('generic_name', 'Generic Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                // validation failed
                $error = array(
                    "success" => false,
                    "message" => "Validation failed"
                );
                echo json_encode($error);
            } else {
                // validation passed
                $data = array(
                    'brand_name' => $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('brand_name')),
                    'generic_name' => $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('generic_name')),
                    'category' => $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('category'))
                );

                $result = $this->Inventory_model->insertProduct($data);
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
        }

Model InventoryModel.php
This is my insertProduct() function in the model, which should be inserting the data into the products table:
        public function insertProduct($data) {
            $this->db->trans_start();

            $this->db->insert('products', array(
                'brand_name' => $this->security->xss_clean($data['brand_name']),
                'generic_name' => $this->security->xss_clean($data['generic_name']),
                'category' => $this->security->xss_clean($data['category'])
            ));

            
            $this->db->trans_complete();

            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                $error = array(
                    "success" => false,
                    "message" => "Error adding product"
                );
                return $error;
            } else {
                try {
                    $query = "SELECT *, selling_price * quantity as total FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC";
                    $result = $this->db->query($query, $product_id);
                    $row = $result->row_array();

                    $total = $row['total'];
                    $badge_class = $row['qty_sold'] < 10 ? 'badge-danger' : 'badge-success';

                    $response = array(
                        "success" => true,
                        "data" => array(
                            "brand_name" => $row['brand_name'],
                            "generic_name" => $row['generic_name'],
                            "category" => $row['category']
                        )
                    );
                    return $response;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $error = array(
                        "success" => false,
                        "message" => "Error retrieving product data"
                    );
                    return $error;
                }
            }
        }


Print your last query for debug by putting this line below where your insert query run.
echo $this->db->last_query(); die;

After the query is printed, run it in your database and see if any error is coming.

Is it not inserting, or is it not returning the last inserted row after insert? I see nothing wrong with your controller/insert code, but in the else in insertProduct you're using a $product_id variable in $this->db->query($query, $product_id); that is not defined and there are also no placeholders in $query for a product_id - this could be causing problems.

So what does happen?  Which message is displayed?  What debugging have you tried, for eg does insertProduct() actually run?  If yes, what does the $data it receives look like?  What does the generated insert query look like?  Does it actually work if you run it in a DB client?  As already pointed out you have some bugs in the next SELECT part of the code as $product_id is not defined. Maybe comment that stuff out and move on to fixing it after you have the insert working.
